# Sprite flipping in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

i am super new to unity and i was messing around with a 2D Rpg, i downloaded an asset from the store (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/environments/tiny-rpg-town-environment-88293) and i wanted to make my player change direction when he turns in a given direction, but the file only comes with up, down and left. i have looked online and cant find any way to flip the left sprite to right and then save it as its own sprite, [trying to enter the sprite like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KvM1.png), sorry if i have explained this in a bad way adn thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

In Unity you can change the flip of a sprite using these options:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipY.html